# how to add two numbers and display result in heading in javascript

Tags: javascript, average, addition

i need to take two numbers from the user input and add them, then display it in a heading like "the total is () " and other function to display the average of them. i tried this code but when i click on the button nothing happen and no result shows to me. can you please help me figure the error

```js
var count = 0;

function start() {
  var i = document.getElementById("computeAvg");
  i.addEventListener("click", add, false);
}

function add() {
  var a, b, c;
  a = Number(document.getElementById("quiz1").value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById("quiz2").value);
  c = a + b;
  document.getElementById("sTotal").value = c;
}

function Avg() {
  count = count + 1
  var d = document.getElementById("sTotal");
  var A = x1 + x2 / count;
  var av = document.getElementById("cAvg");
  av.innerHTML = A;
  document.getElementById("myimg").onclick = Avg() {
    document.getElementById("myimg").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}

window.onload = start;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Quiz Grade Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Quiz Grade Calculator</h2>
  <div style="width:45%;">
    <img id="myimg" src="check.png" style="float:right; visibility:hidden;">
    <div>QUIZ1 <input type="text" size="2" id="quiz1" value="0" onchange="Add()" /> / 5</div>
    <div>QUIZ2 <input type="text" size="2" id="quiz2" value="0" onchange="Add()" /> / 5</div>
  </div>
  <h3>Student Total: <span id="sTotal">0</span></h3>
  <input type="button" id="computeAvg" value="Add Quiz" onclick="Add()"> CLASS AVERAGE <input type="text" size="5" id="cAvg" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the console of your browser. There will be a syntax error.

Comment: put your script after body tag, your script tag cannot see the DOM nodes when it is executed

Comment: @SumedhChakravorty Hence the `window.onload=start;`

Comment: i checked there is no syntax error, and i tried to put the script after the body and nothing changes , no action happend

Answer (score 1):

---

**Problems that I could find**

1. You used the format `.onlick = namedFunction() { ... }`, which is incorrect. Replace the function name with the keyword `function`.
2. Your HTML calls the function `Add()` with a capital letter, but the function is defined as `add()`.
3. You try to change the `value` of a `span` element, but only `input` elements can have values. Instead, you need the `innerText` property.

---

**Other edits I've made**

1. The function `Avg()` is never used, so I put it into a javascript comment.
2. When trying to find errors, it's always good to minimise code, so I've removed tags such as `body`, `html` or `head` which are unnecessary to reproduce the problem.
3. For the purpose of creating a code snippet, I've separated out HTML and javascript. However, I would recommend doing this on a real website as well.

---

**Working code snippet**

```js
var count = 0;

function start() {
  var i = document.getElementById("computeAvg");
  i.addEventListener("click", add, false);
}

function add() {
  var a, b, c;
  a = Number(document.getElementById("quiz1").value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById("quiz2").value);
  c = a + b;
  document.getElementById("sTotal").innerText = c;
}

/*function Avg() {
  count = count + 1
  var d = document.getElementById("sTotal");
  var A = x1 + x2 / count;
  var av = document.getElementById("cAvg");
  av.innerHTML = A;
  document.getElementById("myimg").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("myimg").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}*/

window.onload = start;
```

```html
<h2>Quiz Grade Calculator</h2>
<div style="width:45%;">
  <img id="myimg" src="check.png" style="float:right; visibility:hidden;">
  <div>QUIZ1 <input type="text" size="2" id="quiz1" value="0" onchange="add()" /> / 5</div>
  <div>QUIZ2 <input type="text" size="2" id="quiz2" value="0" onchange="add()" /> / 5</div>
</div>
<h3>Student Total: <span id="sTotal">0</span></h3>
<input type="button" id="computeAvg" value="Add Quiz" onclick="add()"> CLASS AVERAGE <input type="text" size="5" id="cAvg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a numbers of mistakes, the mains of are:

- in function `add` you should use `document.getElementById("sTotal").innerHTML = c;` instead `value` due to `span` does not have `value`.
- an `Add()` and `add()` different names, while `add` is defined `Add` is not.
- in `document.getElementById("myimg").onclick = Avg() {`, you forget about `function`, that cause syntax error.

```js
var count = 0;

function start() {
  var i = document.getElementById("computeAvg");
  i.addEventListener("click", add, false);
}


function add() {
  var a, b, c;
  debugger
  a = Number(document.getElementById("quiz1").value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById("quiz2").value);
  c = a + b;
  document.getElementById("sTotal").innerHTML = c;
}


function Avg() {
  count = count + 1
  var d = document.getElementById("sTotal");
  var A = x1 + x2 / count;
  var av = document.getElementById("cAvg");
  av.innerHTML = A;
  
  document.getElementById("myimg").onclick = function Avg() {
    document.getElementById("myimg").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}


window.onload = start;
```

```html
<h2>Quiz Grade Calculator</h2>
<div style="width:45%;">
  <img id="myimg" src="check.png" style="float:right; visibility:hidden;">
  <div>QUIZ1 <input type="text" size="2" id="quiz1" value="0" onchange="add()" /> / 5</div>
  <div>QUIZ2 <input type="text" size="2" id="quiz2" value="0" onchange="add()" /> / 5</div>
</div>
<h3>Student Total: <span id="sTotal">0</span></h3>
<input type="button" id="computeAvg" value="Add Quiz" onclick="add()"> CLASS AVERAGE <input type="text" size="5" id="cAvg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Quiz Grade Calculator</title> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var count =0;

    function start()
        {
            //var q1 = document.getElementById("quiz1");
            //q1.addEventListener("click",Add,false);
           // var q2 = document.getElementById("quiz2");
            // q2.addEventListener("click",Add,false);
            var i = document.getElementById("computeAvg");
            i.addEventListener("click", add, false);
            }


       function add() {
            var a = document.getElementById("quiz1").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("quiz2").value;
            var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
            document.getElementById("sTotal").innerHTML = c;
            Avg();
        }


         function Avg()
        {  
            // since the number of count is predifine
             count = 2;
             document.getElementById("cAvg").value = (parseInt(document.getElementById("quiz1").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("quiz2").value)) / count;
             document.getElementById("myimg").onclick = Avg();
             document.getElementById("myimg").style.visibility = "visible";

         }

    window.onload=start;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Quiz Grade Calculator</h2>
    <div style="width:45%;">
        <img id="myimg" src="check.png" style="float:right; visibility:hidden;">  
        <div>QUIZ1 <input type="text" size="2" id="quiz1" value="0" onchange="Add()"/> / 5</div>
        <div>QUIZ2 <input type="text" size="2" id="quiz2" value="0" onchange="Add()"/> / 5</div>
    </div>
    <h3>Student Total: <span id="sTotal">0</span></h3>
    <input type = "button" id="computeAvg" value = "Add Quiz" onclick="Add()">
    CLASS AVERAGE <input type="text" size="5" id="cAvg"/> 
</body>
```